# How can I select from mysql table where value is not...?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Input:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * 
         FROM data 
         ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Result:

```
id    name   status
1     dog    ok
2     frog
```

Input:

```
 $result = $db->query('SELECT * 
             FROM data 
             WHERE status = `ok`
             ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Result:

```
id    name   status
1     dog    ok
```

Input:

```
 $result = $db->query('SELECT * 
             FROM data 
             WHERE status != `ok`
             ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Result:

```
id    name   status
```

Input:

```
 $result = $db->query('SELECT * 
             FROM data 
             WHERE status <> `ok`
             ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Result:

```
id    name   status
```

The result I wish to have is WHERE status is NOT `ok`

```
id    name   status
2     frog
```

Comment: the field `status` is nullable?

Comment: $result = $db->query("SELECT * 
             FROM data 
             WHERE status = ''
             ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: @Gadonski no not NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE status <> 'ok' ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

or if you are looking for rows with empty status try...

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE status = '' ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If you want to use single quotes instead use the following:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE status <> \'ok\' ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

*Notice the quotes escaped with slashes.*

Comment: Can you show an example where I can use `'SELECT` instead of `"SELECT`

Comment: The error was because I didn't have quotes escaped with slashes

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE status NOT LIKE 'ok';`

or if the field is Nullable

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE status IS NULL;`

Comment: Your first approch is giving me the results frog and dog

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it's more like the way you worded your requirement:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * 
    FROM `data` 
    WHERE NOT `status` = "ok"
    ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: He is looking for NOT 'ok'.

Comment: Exactly. This should return the rows where status = 'ok' is not true.

Comment: missed the NOT after WHERE. Sorry!

Comment: ERROR:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`ok`

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, then added the NOT. Look at your quotes - are they backticks or single quotes? If backticks, change to single quotes and escape them or use double quotes. I'll edit the answer